# Did I set up memache correctly?

Tags: 7, caching

I have applied [memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) by via instructions from this [page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-memcached-under-rhel-fedora-centos/) to our production server. The difference in numbers don't look stellar.

My question: **Did I configure memcache improperly? Can I increase the `CACHESIZE` to perhaps get a better overall performance?**

**Settings.php**

In settings.php, I've included this bit of text as recommend by the README.txt inside the memcache module.

```
/**************************************************
 * MEMCACHE
 **************************************************/
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
$conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

// The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

// Don't bootstrap the database when serving pages from the cache.
$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;

$conf['memcache_servers'] = array('server:11211' => 'default');
```

**Memcache Conf**

The memcache system conf has been left it's default:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS=""
```

**Benchmarks**

I ran a battery of apache benchmark tests and these are the numbers

*With* memcache active

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    1   0.4      1       4
Processing:     4   50   8.6     52      62
Waiting:        4   50   8.6     52      62
Total:          7   51   8.2     53      63
```

Without / Before / Baseline

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    1   0.5      1       4
Processing:     3   50   8.4     52      61
Waiting:        3   50   8.4     52      60
Total:          7   51   7.9     53      62
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up increasing the RAM in the conf file. Since I've noticed no  evictions. In fact the eviction stat is at 0 at the moment.